# Android Dialog in Custom Style: Remove Blue Line and set ActionBar Color

Tags: android, dialog

I am creating a custom Dialog with the following code and the view as follow:
mCountryDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
However, i want to remove the blue divider and change the background color of the "action bar"

[image]

**Attempted Result**
With reference to stackoverflow, i created a custom dialog style in style.xml

```
`<style name="LoCountryDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo"> 
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/main_theme_red</item>
```

`

I would change the background color from black to red but the "Topbar" which shows Time, battery level ,etc was gone and the blue divider line remains here.
It will be great if anyone would share the solution with me, many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: have you tried this: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

Comment: I used that tool to generate a custom editText box, which is useful.
However, this time i want to change color of actionbar within a dialog..is it possible for you to give me more hint on using that tool, many thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Simply add this line to your Dialog.onCreateView() Method:

```html
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: But i want to keep the content of the title, what i want is to remove the "underline" only..

Answer (score 0):

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

> It will generate all necessary nine patch assets plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight into your project.

You create a theme with these styles similar like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

after this you apply your theme to your entire app or individual activities:

for further reading, please see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: i think I got your idea. I will try your method later and will accept this as the answer if it is sccuessful. Thanks in advance!